# PDF Annotation sidebar / increase width of document

Tags: pdf, annotation

I recently bought a Surface 3 pro tablet, and really love the ability to annotate pdf documents using the stylus.

Still, for scribbling along my thoughts while reading a document, I would need more space beside the document content.

Is there some tool that I can use to increase the width of the pages within a document (so I would have a sidebar for annotations)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this online tool: https://pdfresizer.com/crop

It's very simple, but does the job. Upload your PDF file and select "Extend margins" option, it will let you enter arbitrary size for each margin.

[image: Extend margins tool in action]